# MySQL: "Access Denied"

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, registration

I am trying to implant facebook registration on my site.

I used this tutorial: http://www.9lessons.info/2011/01/user-signup-using-facebook-data.html

When I click 'register' and it's time for the code to insert the data into the database I get this error:

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for
>   user 'USERNAME'@'HOST' (using password: YES) in
>   /home/a9297472/public_html/store_user_data.php on line 44

(I censored the real username and host)

According to the error the host and username were right.
Here is the process code:

```
<?php
include('config/db_con.php');
define('FACEBOOK_APP_ID', 'APP ID'); // Place your App Id here
define('FACEBOOK_SECRET', 'APP SECRET'); // Place your App Secret Here

// No need to change the function body
function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) 
{
    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
    // decode the data
    $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
    $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);
    if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256')
    {
        error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
        return null;
    }

    // check sig
    $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
    if ($sig !== $expected_sig) 
    {
        error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
        return null;
    }
    return $data;
}
function base64_url_decode($input) 
{
    return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}
if ($_REQUEST) 
{
    $response = parse_signed_request(
        $_REQUEST['signed_request'],
        FACEBOOK_SECRET
    );

    $name = $response["registration"]["name"];
    $email = $response["registration"]["email"];
    $password = $response["registration"]["password"];
    $gender = $response["registration"]["gender"];
    $dob = $response["registration"]["birthday"];

    // Connecting to database
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    // Inserting into users table
    $result = mysql_query("
INSERT INTO users (
    name, email, password, gender, dob
) VALUES (
    '$name', '$email', '$password', '$gender', '$dob')
");

    if($result){
    // User successfully stored
    }
    else
    {
        // Error in storing
    }
}
else 
{
    echo '$_REQUEST is empty';
}

?>
```

I double checked everything.
The host,username,password & db_name are the same details I use in other parts of the site and it works fine.
What did I do wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You also shouldn't post your appID and secret as someone can now perform actions on behalf of your app :-) I would suggest editing your post to block out the secret, then reset it the [developer app](http://www.facebook.com/developers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `$password` for the db is being overwritten here:

`$password = $response["registration"]["password"];`

I assume you want to use the one from db_con.php
;)

Comment: Nice catch! Another tip: declare your DB-credentials as constants, so that you don't actually overwrite them in your script.

Comment: Nice catch indeed! Didn't see that there :D That wasnt the only problem though. I also changed `INSERT INTO users (name, email, password, gender, dob) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$password', '$gender', '$dob'));`  - I added ` around the field names :) --   Thank you!